How to implement Bootstrap Card Layout in HTML: Achieving Desired Design vs. Current Output
I'm working on a Django application. I'm mostly working on the backend because of that in the frontend I'm terrible. I want to create a page that contains a couple of cards. I want to create this structure in the image-1 but I'm able to create image-2. I'll attach my code, can you help me to implement the first image? (the images in the picture is not important they can change)
I'm using bootstrap 4.6

<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12">
            <img class="ca-icon" src="{% static 'images/list-icon.svg' %}" alt="List">
            <div class="row ca-border mb-3 align-items-center ca-side-context">
                <div class="col-6 ">
                    <div class="row">Text-1</div>
                    <div class="row "><img class="icon sound-icon" src="{% static 'images/sound-icon.svg' %}"
                                           alt="Sound Icon"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6  ca-border"><img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'images/temp.png' %}" alt="List"></div>
            </div>

            <img class="ca-icon" src="{% static 'images/parent-icon.svg' %}" alt="List">
            <div class="row ca-border mb-3 align-items-center ca-side-context">
                <div class="col-6 ">
                    <div class="row">Text-2</div>
                    <div class="row "><img class="icon sound-icon" src="{% static 'images/sound-icon.svg' %}"
                                           alt="Sound Icon"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6  ca-border"><img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'images/temp.png' %}" alt="List"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<style>
.ca-border {
        border: 12px solid #ffdd43;
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .ca-icon {
        width: 10%;
       height: 10%;
    }
    .sound-icon {
        width: 50%;
       height: 50%;
    }
    .play-icon{
        width: 90%;
       height: 90%;
    }
    .clock-icon{
        width: 50%;
       height: 50%;
    }
    .subject-title {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .statement {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .ca-frame {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
</style>


Although you are using Django for backend, this question has nothing to do with Django thus no need to have Django tag. It's mainly bootstrap and frontend

Simply, your icons need to be positioned absolutely in relation to the containing card.
